# Shopware 6 : How to get dynamic url in custom plugin controller?

Tags: plugins, shopware6

**Shopware 6**

I am new to shopware. I want base url in controller ( custom plugin ).

I tried this but it's not working for me.

```
$salesChannel->getDomains()->first()->getUrl();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** : Add this namespace

```
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
```

**Second** : here you can get base url.

```
    $urls = [];
    $salesChannelRepository = $this->container->get('sales_channel.repository');
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addAssociation('domains');
    $salesChannelIds = $salesChannelRepository->search($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext());
    foreach($salesChannelIds->getEntities()->getElements() as $key => $salesChannel){
        foreach($salesChannel->getDomains()->getElements() as $element){
            array_push($urls, $element->getUrl());
        }
    }
```

**you will get your url in *$urls* variable.**

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the current host and base url in your controller:

```php
use Shopware\Storefront\Framework\Routing\RequestTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// ...

/**
 * @Route(...)
 */
public function myAction(Request $request): Response
{
    $host = $request->attributes->get(RequestTransformer::SALES_CHANNEL_ABSOLUTE_BASE_URL)
        . $request->attributes->get(RequestTransformer::SALES_CHANNEL_BASE_URL);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the request object which you should have in a controller, you have access to an request attribute called `sw-storefront-url`. This will give you exactly what you need: the base-url of the current request.
See also [How to get the current saleschannel domain in Shopware 6 storefront/TWIG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74782710/how-to-get-the-current-saleschannel-domain-in-shopware-6-storefront-twig/74782711#74782711)